# How to using dlply to apply breakpoints function of package strucchange to subsets of data ?[R]

Tags: r, plyr, piecewise

Well,

I try to do some piecewise regression on my data to find eventual breakpoint for each ID and extract this information.

Example: subset of my personal data

```
 ID     time     y
7G009   0       9
7G009   108,33  13
7G009   185,69  16
7G009   309,22  20
7G009   515,08  21
7G051   0       10
7G051   108,33  14
7G051   185,69  19
7G051   309,22  23
7G051   515,08  25
8S027   0       8
8S027   108,33  13
8S027   185,69  17
8S027   309,22  22
8S027   515,08  23
```

For that purpose , I used the breakpoints function of package strucchange and dlply , my code is the following :

```
breakby=dlply(test,.(subject),summarize,break=breakpoints(y~time,h=2))
```

but I get an error :

```
Erreur dans breakpoints.formula(nbf ~ cumggd, h = 2) :
minimum segment size must be greater than the number of regressors
```

Well, if anybody can tell me how deal with it

Thank you in advance.

Sorry for the poor English.

Comment: Do you know how to do what you want if you just had one ID to do this task for?

Comment: Yes , i know different way . i test for example with the strucchange package( breakpoint()) , or with the segmented package(with segemented()). I try also with the siZer package (piecewise.linear) but i am stuck when i want to deal with all my Ids

Comment: Why don't you post the code you would use to test for a single ID and explain why you're having trouble doing the same type of thing over all the IDs

Comment: This may not be interesting for you any more, but I think the problem is the specification `h=2` - you have 2 regressors, so your h must be at least 3.